# Use get() method to grab all categories and output inside another method

Tags: php, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have the below get method that I would like to use as a template to output my category names into an output method:

```
public static function get()
{
    $recipe_categories = get_terms('recipe_categories');
    var_dump($recipe_categories);

    foreach ($recipe_categories as $member_group_term) {

        $member_group_query = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'recipe',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'recipe_categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array($member_group_term->slug),
                    'operator' => 'IN'
                )
            )
        ));

        var_dump($member_group_query);
    }
}
```

Here is the output method that I have:

```
public function output()
{
    // @todo: Grab get() and output
}
```

I can't get it to print out all the 'name' attributes:

Here is what i'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp_pluck_list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) like so:

```
wp_pluck_list($recipe_categories, 'name');
```

Which should return:

```
array(
    'Bread',
    'Breakfast',
    'Cocktails'
)
```